# Typeface in xml from another class

Tags: android, xml

I am using a text view for font awesome icon.and setting typeface programmatically`.

```
findviewbyid(R.id.mytextview).setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(getApplicationContext(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
```

is it possible to set typeface from another class
? i know there is one attribute  .

```
android:typeface
```

i want to set that above typeface in xml.please dont ask me why i need it.thank you..FontManager class is given below

```
public class FontManager {
public static final String ROOT = "fonts/",
        FONTAWESOME = ROOT + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf";

public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class that extends TextView and override a few methods to accomplish what you need:

TypeFaceTextView:

```
public class TypefaceTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public TypefaceTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypefaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public TypefaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                        int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.TypefaceTextView);

    try {

        CharSequence typeText = a.getString(R.styleable.TypefaceTextView_typeText);
        TypeText type = TypeText.valueOf(String.valueOf(typeText));
        switch (type){
            case title:
                setTypeface(Typefaces.getTitleLatoTypeface(getContext()));
                break;
            case body:
                setTypeface(Typefaces.getBodyLatoTypeface(getContext()));
                break;
            case footer:
                setTypeface(Typefaces.getFooterLatoTypeface(getContext()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

private enum TypeText{
    title,
    body,
    footer
}

}
```

Create a file called attrs.xml in values folder and declare the stylable used in TypeFaceTextView:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="TypefaceTextView">
    <attr name="typeText" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then in your xml you can use it like this:

```
<com.playtown.set_br.utils.TypefaceTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    ...
    app:typeText="title" />
```

Here is my TypeFaces class just in case you need it:

```
public class Typefaces {

public static Typeface getTitleLatoTypeface(Context context){
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Lato-Bold.ttf");
}

public static Typeface getFooterLatoTypeface(Context context){
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Lato-Hairline.ttf");
}

public static Typeface getBodyLatoTypeface(Context context){
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Lato-Regular.ttf");
}
}
```

Comment: It's no complex, just an implementation of textview. If you want to use a class with a custom behavior you have to implement it!